# Reporting Server Credential Issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2012-r2

We have performance tracking reports that refresh every 5 minutes to allow operators to continuously track how they're doing.  We operate 24/7 and these operator PC's do not log-off.  When we first pull up these reports Report Server will occasionally ask us for our Windows Credentials.  Once entered the report will run and auto-refresh for the rest of the day.  But after about 24 hours or so a refresh will fail and require the credentials to be refreshed.  Either by entering them in when prompted, locking/unlocking Windows, or by logging off and back on.  Most of our operators do not know the shared windows account and password that their PC uses.

We're looking for a configuration change on the Server that would allow any user that knows the link to the rdl to be able to view the reports without needing to enter credentials.  We are using Windows Server 2012. The data source credentials are saved in each data source, the credentials are being prompted by the server, and not by the report itself.

Comment: Shared windows account and PW for all PCs... if this is true, it's about as secure as removing the password all together or making it 1234. Also, SSRS doesn't support Windows authentication in conjunction with anonymous authentication. You'd have to explicitly use forms authentication and make it anonymous .

Comment: I'm with @scsimon if you have no issue with everyone having access to all of the reports, why bother with any security? Seems like a terrible practice, but you're already basically doing that so why not go 100% unprotected?